# Problem with JavaMail when create text/html to send

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime

When you sent an email with html the email has inside:

```
<html> = 09
= 09 = 09 <! - NAME: 1 COLUMN ->
= 09 = 09 <! - [if gte mso 15]>
= 09 = 09 <xml>
= 09 = 09 = 09 <or: OfficeDocumentSettings>
= 09 = 09 = 09 </ o: OfficeDocumentSettings>
= 09 = 09 </ xml>
= 09 = 09 <! [Endif] ->
= 09 = 09 <meta charset = 3D "UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv = 3D "X-UA-Compatible" content = 3D "IE = 3Dedge">
        <meta name = 3D "viewport" content = 3D "width = 3Ddevice-width, initial-sc =
ale = 3D1 ">
```

the = 09 = 09 and = 3D cause the email body to not work properly.
causing that in some buttons that I have in html the parameters do not work

```
MimeMessage mail = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMultipart multi = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeBodyPart textHtml = new MimeBodyPart();

if (html.isEmpty()) {
  textPart.setText(text, "utf-8");
  multi.addBodyPart(textPart);
} else {                     
  textHtml.setContent(MimeUtility.decodeText(html), "text/html");
  textHtml.setHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML");

  multi.addBodyPart(textHtml);
}

mail.setContent(multi);
mail.setSubject(subject);
mail.setFrom(from);
mail.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to[0].toString());
mail.saveChanges();
this.mailSender.send(mail);
```

Please help!

Comment: If you are sending a dynamic html then it may not work, depends or application service provider and browser. Cant you create it statically before sending it ? How are you trying to send it and where?

Comment: Yes, the mail is always the same, I send it to myself and it is sent through an SMTP server

Comment: if you are using some kind of javascript for dynamic things  , then it will not work , you need to create static html page first and then email it and if you have images then content type as text/html will not work , you need to do base 64 encoding and send encoded value of an image in html , then it will get viewed

Comment: so is it through gmail or some service provider ? or your own SMTP server ? What are the thing that are failing (not clear in your email). As @MonisMajeed said try and encode your whole page.

Comment: How can I encrypt the email to 64? @MonisMajeed

Comment: you can do by online https://www.base64decode.org/ or if using java check https://dzone.com/articles/base64-encoding-java-8

Comment: The SMTP server is typical of the company. The problem is that I have a button to accept: <button style = 3D "background =
: # 393939! Important;
    padding: 10px! important;
    margin: 10px 0 5px! important;
    font-size: 14px! important;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px # 0000004a;
    color: #fff;
    width: 10%;
    font-weight: bold; "type = 3D" submit "> OK </ button>
If you can see inside each Attribute add a = 3D then when reading the email it does not work well @Raghuveer

Comment: I'm going to try it @MonisMajeed

Comment: I have already modified the mail to base64 but how do I do it so that the mail does not arrive encrypted?

Comment: The "=09" is the quoted-printable encoding of the message, the receiving mailer will decode it.  When you set the content of the message you're calling MimeUtility,decodeText, why?  That should not be needed.  Try getting rid of that and if it still doesn't work post the complete MIME content of the message.